# the select doesn't post the selected item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, drop-down-menu

On the **HttpPost** I do not get the selected drop down value.
All other values in the model that is being posted exists.
the `CountryList` is being posted as null.

The `selectedCountryID` is the same as initialized in the Get.
The int value stays the same no matter whatever I select in the dropdown.
I don't need the list - just the selected value.

Project is using **Core Net 2.2/ MVC**

### Model

```cs
    public class GuestRequestModel 
    {
        [Display(Name = "Select Country", Description = "Select Country")]
        public int SelectedCountryID { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CountryList { get; set; }
    }
```

### Controller

```cs
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
       var listDTO = guestRequestRepository.GetCountryList();
       var listForVM = listDTO.Select(t => new SelectListItem
       {
            Text = t.Description_EN,
            Value = t.ID.ToString()
        });
        model.CountryList = listForVM;
        model.SelectedCountryID = country.ID;
        return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(GuestRequestModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {// no selected value here}
    }
```

### View

```cs
    @model GuestStudentWF.Models.GuestRequestModel
    <form asp-action="Create">         
        <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="SelectedCountryID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="SelectedCountryID" asp-items="Model.CountryList">
                    <option>Please select one</option>
                </select>
            </div>
    </form>
```

I have tried changing the `SelectedCountryID`  to string - it didn't make a diffrence.
Could be that I am missing something fondumental in the **MVC-Razor** concept

Comment: How are you submitting the form?  Submit button or via ajax?  Can I see the html in the form tag as its rendered in the browser?

Comment: I use Submit button

Comment: I'd still like to see the html rendered to the browser

Comment: this is the rendered code : https://pastebin.com/CdvQe1UC

Comment: this is the full original View https://pastebin.com/WsV33QBm

Comment: SelectedCountryID stay 30 like declared in the HttpGet, no matter what the user chose in the dropdown. Site.js is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your issue.  You are declaring SelectedCountryID twice.  Line 17 of your view

`<div><input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Select Country field is required." id="SelectedCountryID" name="SelectedCountryID" value="30" /></div>`

Comment: It was hidden field before, now it works. You are my hero. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me and it was because my select control was not within the form tags.